# functional tests in silex cant find translator.messages

Tags: symfony1, silex

i have /src/app.php that contains my silex app and in this app there is some translation that gets passes to twig, which works fine:

```
$app['twig']->render('index.twig', array('title' => $app['translator']->trans('homepage')));
```

but in my functional test this causes an exception:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

So i guess the $app['translator.messages'] is not present in the test.

in /tests/functional/ApplicationTest.php in the createApplication() method, i can var_dump the
`$this->app['translator.messages']` and get the full array.

but when in the actual test method var_dump outputs: `.bool(true)`

in app.php the translation.messages are included so:

```
 $app['translator.messages'] = require_once  __DIR__ . '/../resources/locales/translations.php';
```

do i miss some step here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit tricky. The problem is that you are using `require_once`. This means that the messages will only be required at the first test, but at no subsequent tests.

To solve your problem, simply change it to `require`.